# Print for loop results in one line and sort

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, python-3.x, collatz

```
for n in range(1,1000000):
    print(n)
    result = []
    for x in range(1,3000001):
        if n%2==0:
            x=n/2
        else:
            x=3*n+ 1
        n=x
        result.append(n)
        if n==1:
            break
    print(len(result))
n+=1
```

I want these results to be printed in an array or something like that.I mean like this.

3,1,7,2,5,8,1,..

Then I want to take the highest element and its index.How can I do that?Thank you.

Comment: An array for each iteration in outer loop?

Comment: Yeah.I want to print the results into an array and find the max value and its index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.join` for the first task:

```
>>> result = [4, 0, 9, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5]
>>> print (', '.join(map(str, result)))
4, 0, 9, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 5
```

And `max` with `enumerate` for the second task:

```
>>> ind, val = max(enumerate(result), key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> ind, val
(2, 9)
```

Comment: I don't have a list.I only have values which are come from the for loop.so how can I print those into an array and find the max value and its index?

Comment: @user2297793 In your code you're clearly appending items to the `result` list. Except `print(n)` and `print(len(result))` you're printing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you separate out the loop that does the work into its own function, this becomes much easier.

```
def collatz_length(n):
    result = []
    for x in range(1,3000001):
        if n%2==0:
            x=n/2
        else:
            x=3*n+ 1
        n=x
        result.append(n)
        if n==1:
            break
    return len(result)


print(max((collatz_length(i + 1), i) for i in range(1000000)))
```

Since you're not using `result`, just its length, you could simplify (and speed up) the function a little by simply counting

You can tidy up the calculation of x by using a [ternary expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

```
def collatz_length(n):
    for c in range(1, 3000001):
        x = 3 * n + 1 if n % 2 else n / 2
        n = x
        if n == 1:
            return c
```

Comment: I don't have a list.I only have values which are come from the for loop.so how can I print those into an array and find the max value and its index?

Comment: @user2297793, you are looking for the longest of the results?